Mendeley to LaTeX bibliography
I am struggling with citetion from LaTeX using the Mendeley Reference Manager. I already connected Mendeley references with LaTeX with the commands (Open LaTeX --> upload/From Mendeley) and I have my reference.bib file in LaTeX. Then with commands in LaTeX (\usepackage{cite} % Required for inserting citations
\usepackage{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package
\addbibresource{sample.bib}  %Import the bibliography file
\printbibliography %Prints bibliography) I set up the citation "system". Then writing the text I do \cite{} and a lsit of papers which are the ones in the reference.bib file appears and I can select which one I want to citeate.
Example of the problem:
@article{exampleheading,
    title = {{ExampleTitle}},
    year = {exampleyear},
    journal = {},
    author = {exampleauthor},
    number = {},
    pages = {},
    volume = {},
    publisher = {},
    url = {},
    isbn = {},
    doi = {},
    issn = {},
    keywords = {}
}

when I do \cite{the list here is the list of exampleheading} which is fine but then when I recompile I still have the citation as (exampleheading) instead of (exampleauthor, exampleyear).
Plus another problem is: I wish to directly connect Mendeley to LaTeX without me uploading the Mendeley reference.bib anytime. I have tried going in Mendeley --> Tools --> Options to then select the export of Bibtex files, But problem is that Mendeley does not have options in tools anymore.
Can you please suggest me a way to syncronize directly Mendeley to LaTeX?
Thank you a lor for the help! :)
I have tried for the first problem: connected Mendeley references with LaTeX with the commands (Open LaTeX --> upload/From Mendeley) and I have my reference.bib file in LaTeX. Then with commands in LaTeX (\usepackage{cite} % Required for inserting citations
\usepackage{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package
\addbibresource{sample.bib}  %Import the bibliography file
\printbibliography %Prints bibliography) I set up the citation "system".
I have tried this for the second problem: Mendeley --> Tools --> Options.

The cite package is for bibliographies created via bibtex, not for biblatex. Decide which of these two different bibliography methods you want to use, but don't mix them.

Which latex editor do you use?

Is your .bib file called references.bib or sample.bib?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
